# Integrate Djpeewee into Django to encrypt sqlite3 database

Tags: django, sqlcipher, peewee, pysqlite, pysqlcipher

I would like to encrypt a sqlite3 database that is used by my Django project. For this purpose I would like to use pysqlcipher.

Since I haven't found any ways to easily integrate pysqlcipher with Django I started wondering if it would be possible to integrate Djpeewee into my existing Django project and then through Djpeewee encrypt and decrypt my sqlite3 database since originally PeeWee supports sqlcipher encryptions.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Since I haven't found a way to do it eventually I decided not to encrypt the whole database (using pysqlcipher) but instead encrypted single fields in this database using [django-fernet-fields](https://github.com/orcasgit/django-fernet-fields).

As a result one can still open the database and see its structure and tables, but individual entries and encrypted. This is enough for my required level of security. On top django-fernet-fields is very easy to use!

Maybe you might consider the same for your project if pysqlcipher will not work?

Answer (score 0):

What about writing a subclass of the Django `SqliteDatabase` implementation that uses the `pysqlcipher` library as the backend? That seems to me the best solution if you're already using Django.